# Wordpress - list posts by modified date

Tags: wordpress

How do I list my posts in Wordpress ordered by modified date instead of created date?

I have it as

```
<?php $posts=query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=post_modified&order=ASC'); ?>  
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Having orderby=title does sort the posts by title but my above query doesn't work.
Looks like orderby=post_modified isn't recognized.

Answer (score 4):

Ah ok... I figured it out.
orderby=post_modified needs to be orderby=modified.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: The reference page for WP_Query https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query says that 'post_modified' will work now. It certainly works for me.